# How do you ask the user questions in an OS X installer built with pkgbuild/productbuild?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I'm building an installer using pkgbuild and productbuild, and I want part of the process to involve asking the user some simple questions. These questions can be answered by either check boxes (yes/no) or a small one-line text input field.

Once those questions are asked, I want to feed them to a postinstall script.

For more context, my product is a set of command-line tools that will live in /usr/local/X, where X is the name of my product. Then, a simple postinstall script is run to set some things up initially. pkgbuild already takes care of this nicely. What I'd really like is for the postinstall script to be provided the answers to my questions, maybe in an environment variable, so it can set things up accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do without writing custom plugins.

Comment: I've been looking for custom plugin reference. Is there a newer example than this deprecated packagebuild plugin reference? http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/InstallerPluginSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Installer_Plugins/index.html may also help